# USB 3.0 ports not working after suspend

Tags: 13.04, usb, suspend, ultrabook

I have a Samsung Series 9 NP900X4C ultrabook, and since I upgraded to 12.10 and then 13.04, my USB 3.0 ports (two on the right side) don't work anymore after my computer wakes up from suspend mode.

I need to restart my computer to get these two USB 3.0 ports working again.

My USB 2.0 port (one on the left side) doesn't encounter this issue. How do I fix this?

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level
on
auto
auto
auto
auto
auto
```

Comment: The easiest way is to install TLP and check ++USB section ..http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: I added the cat output. And I didn't install TLP. I checked the USB section, but I think it's not related...thx

Comment: I configured TLP by disabling the USB autosuspend, but this didn't reactivate the usb 3.0 ports on my expresscard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it going into the BIOS (F2 key when booting up) and activating "USB S3 Wake_up" option under the *Advanced* tab.
[image]

Hope this works for you!

Comment: My BIOS didn't have an option to disable "USB S3 Wake-up", but disabling "legacy USB support" seemed to work for me. Previously, I was holding shift when booting to get the GRUB menu, then booting an older Linux kernel that didn't have the problem.

Comment: I disabled the legacy usb support in my bios but this didn't reactivate the usb 3.0 ports on my expresscard.